# Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
type Arg = Record<PropertyKey, unknown>

function foo(d: Arg) {
  console.log(d)
}

type M<T, D> = {
  type: T,
  data: D
}

type MyType1 = M<'bar', {name: string}>

const a1: MyType1 = {type: 'bar', data: {name: 'xxx'}}

// ok
foo(a1)

interface N<T, D> {
  data: D
  type: T
}

type MyType2 = N<'xyz', {name: number}>
const a2: MyType2 = {type: 'xyz', data: {name: 2}}
// error ??
// Argument of type 'MyType2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'D'.
//  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'N<"xyz", { name: number; }>'.
foo(a2)
```

ts gives me a error when i code like `foo(a2)`, but `foo(a1)` is ok, the difference is a1 use type, a2 use interface. I have no idea why `foo(a2)` is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The Problem here is your usage of the interface keyword.

To make it work you should add all properties of your Record to extends the interface or extending the interface directly with it.

If you are using a type Typescript won't be as strict with that, thats why your first example works

```js
interface N<T, D> {
  data: D
  type: T
}

interface A<T, D> {
    data: D,
    type: T,
    [x: PropertyKey]: unknown
}
interface B<T, D> extends Arg {
    data: D,
    type: T,
}
type MyType2 = N<'xyz', {name: number}>
const a2: MyType2 = {type: 'xyz', data: {name: 2}}
type MyType3 = A<'xyz', {name: number}>
const a3: MyType3 = {type: 'xyz', data: {name: 2}}
type MyType4 = B<'xyz', {name: number}>
const a4: MyType4 = {type: 'xyz', data: {name: 2}}
// error ??
// Argument of type 'MyType2' is not assignable to parameter of type 'D'.
//  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'N<"xyz", { name: number; }>'.
foo(a2)
foo(a3)
foo(a4)
```

Comment: Thanks, Filly,it's helpfull for me